# D3.js reading data from csv file

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I tried re-implementing this chart I found online: http://plnkr.co/edit/5g4lUXnJa3pmWEfFq8rq?p=preview Basically, what I did was changing my x-axis to string instead of integer.

```
    // set the stage
var margin = {t:30, r:20, b:20, l:40 },
    w = 600 - margin.l - margin.r,
    h = 500 - margin.t - margin.b,
    x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0,w], .1) //changed linear to ordinal to accept strings input
    y = d3.scale.linear().range([h - 60, 0]),
    //colors that will reflect geographical regions
    color = d3.scale.category10();

.....

var x0 = Math.max(-d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.trust; }), d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.trust; }));
x.domain(["Drug A", "Drug B", "Drug C", "Drug D", "Drug E", "Drug F"]); //changed this to strings
y.domain([0, 250])
```

But now I seem to have problem with the data plotting. The data currently is showing at my Y-axis only when it should display according to the strings that I have changed. See image here: [image: Click to view Image]

Comment: Check line 107 in the plunkr you are providing. It might be that you are referring to the wrong key in the data object. If that doesn't help, you might want to provide a link to your own code. Also the line 96 you are quoting above refers to `.trust` key - which you are not likely to have. Considering that `x0` is redundant in your code, it doesn't hurt :)

Comment: can you post your plunkr or jsfiddle so we can see your code?

Comment: @PinguinDirk Thanks! That actually helps :)